# how to Update a field with huge html code in oracle

Tags: html, oracle, oracle11g

what is the best way to update a column with 530 lines of html code in a table of datatype clob?
I am trying to update using

```
update table1 set message = '---530 lines of html code which contains lot of tags and special characters'
where messagetype = 'email' and order = 1;
```

I have tried using declaring a variable and 
    storing in it and updating that variable but that doesn't work either
    I have tried this way but no luck

```
set define off;
DECLARE
str cLOB;
BEGIN
str := '500 lines of html code'

update table1 set message = str  where messagetype = 'email' and order = 1;

error:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Comment: is this a merely oracle problem? why is c# tagged? are you trying to update via a c# app?

Comment: please show the table definition

Comment: see here https://community.oracle.com/thread/3941026

Comment: If your '500 lines of code' string is actually a literal value, then it cannot exceed the size of a varchar2 of 32K.  See link.

Comment: @NicoRiff It doesn't relate to c# but some persons canbe familiar with both. So I don't want to miss any chance to find a solution,Sorry thanks

Comment: @OldProgrammer  CREATE TABLE tbl1
(
  emailTYPE  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  old_email  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  order      NUMBER,
  MESSAGE      NCLOB
)

Comment: community.oracle.com/thread/3941026 this seems to be helpful. I will tryand let you know @OldProgrammer

Comment: @OldProgrammer, It helped, I divided the data into chunks and updated. Thanks alot